# /var/tempFS is full 100%! how do I remove files?

Tags: linux, partitioning

```
/var/tempFS           2.9G  2.8G  664K 100% /tmp
```

How can I remove all files in this directory or change the partition size?

Comment: This should be migrated to SU...

Answer (score 1):

If you know which files you don't need, you can use the [**rm**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) command to delete them.

```
cd /tmp
rm <somefile>
```

As to how to increase the size of the partition, it's probably above your level of expertise so I would recommend you get someone in to do it for you.